# line art invisible

Tags: freestyle

I am trying to make my viewport shader render as line art. Line art, grease pencil, freestyle.. i tried everything.
Nothing i do makes any line show anywhere.
I tried all render engines. All settings. No line at all anywhere no matter what i select it looks exactly like before. Nothing changes.
Is there a global super easy to find "show lines" button that everybody on earth knows except me? It must be something so obvious no tutorial even covers it..
Would love to know what i need to do : )
Thankyou

Comment: Hello, do you have at least 1 camera in your scene ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I had one and then also two of them, deleted them and made a new one to see if that worked but it didn't. I have 2.93. Thanks!